# What does "pending" mean in SmartTarget 2011 business manager when updating a promotion

Tags: fredhopper

I am using Tridion 2011 SP1 with SmartTarget business manager to update my already existing promotions.

I have a new component presentation to show as my promotional item, so I have updated existing promotion in business manager with new component presentation and saved it in business manager.

My new component presentation is getting displayed in the promotion page.

But I have seen that the promotion that I have updated in business manger is in **Pending** status. What does this Pending mean?

Answer (score 2):

The Pending status is basically for outscaling. If you only have one Fredhopper instance (e.g. you are not using the sync server and client), you don't need to worry about it.

If you do have multiple synced instances, you can push all the changes across to all clients by clicking the File button in the top-right corner (and going through the subsequent motions of approving and "publishing" it [which is different than Tridion publishing!])

Comment: No problem. If you are happy with this answer, please mark it as accepted.